How to Optimize Content Loading Speed on Odoo Website
I've noticed that the content on my odoo website loads slowly compared to other websites. Specifically, when users visit my site, the content loads gradually as they scroll down, causing a less-than-ideal user experience. In contrast, many other websites load all content at once, providing a smoother browsing experience.
Ideally, I would like the content to be loaded all at once, eliminating the need for users to wait for content to load as they scroll down the page. Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this optimization within the Odoo website builder? I'm using Odoo v16 Enterprise for my website. Any insights, tips, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

What type of content you are showing? Does it have a lot of images/Videos?

my website primarily features an e-commerce shop page where I showcase products along with their respective images.
